# How do I remove duplicated by position SNPs using PLink?

Tags: bioinformatics, genetics

I am working with PLINK to analyse SNP chip data.

Does anyone know how to remove duplicated SNPs (duplicated by position)?

Comment: You might get more answers in the more specialized site https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

If we already have files in plink format then we should have [.bim](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/formats#bim) for binary plink files or [.map](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/formats#map) for text plink files. In either case the positions are on the 3rd column and SNP names are on 2nd column.

We need to create a list of SNPs that are duplicated:

```
sort -k3n myFile.map |  uniq  -f2 -D | cut -f2 > dupeSNP.txt
```

Then run plink with [--exclude](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/filter#snp) flag:

```
plink --file myFile --exclude dupeSNP.txt --out myFileSubset
```

Comment: Dear zx8754, That's works perfectly thanks. Do you have any idea how i can convert .txt files to plink format. Actually that files comes from analyses of each chromosome separately after imputation, so i want combine all output results back to plink. the format of 26 separate files are as: first column is ID, and all other columns are imputed snps?

Comment: @user2808642 if you have a new question post as a separate question. Also provide example data, and expected output.

Comment: Also consider upvoting/accepting as answer if this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it directly in PLINK1.9 using the `--list-duplicate-vars` flag 
together with the `<require-same-ref>`, `<ids-only>`, or `<suppress-first>`  modifiers depending on what you want to do.

check https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/data#list_duplicate_vars for more details

If you want to delete all occurences of a variant with duplicates, you will have to use the `--exclude` flag on the output file of `--list-duplicate-vars` ,
 which should have a `.dupvar` extention.

Answer (score 0):

I should caution that the two answers given below yield different results. This is because the `sort | uniq` method only takes into account `SNP` and `bp location`; whereas, the `PLINK` method (`--list-duplicate-vars`) takes into account `A1` and `A2` as well.

Similar to `sort | uniq` on the `.map` file we could use `AWK` on a `.gen` file, that looks like this:

```
22 rs1 12 A G 1 0 0 1 0 0
22 rs1 12 G A 0 1 0 0 0 1
22 rs2 16 C A 1 0 0 0 1 0
22 rs2 16 C G 0 0 1 1 0 0
22 rs3 17 T CTA 0 0 1 0 1 0
22 rs3 17 CTA T 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

```
# Get list of duplicate rsXYZ ID's
awk -F' ' '{print $2}' chr22.gen |\
        sort |\
        uniq -d > chr22_rsid_duplicates.txt

# Get list of duplicated bp positions
awk -F' ' '{print $3}' chr22.gen |\
        sort |\
        uniq -d > chr22_location_duplicates.txt

# Now match this list of bp positions to gen file to get the rsid for these locations
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$3 in a{print $2}' \
        chr22_location_duplicates.txt \
        chr22.gen |\
        sort |\
        uniq \
        > chr22_rsidBylocation_duplicates.txt

cat chr22_rsid_duplicates.txt \
        chr22_rsidBylocation_duplicates.txt \
        > tmp

# Get list of duplicates (by location and/or rsid)
cat tmp | sort | uniq > chr22_duplicates.txt

plink --gen chr22.gen \
        --sample chr22.sample \
        --exclude chr22_duplicates.txt  \
        --recode oxford \
        --out chr22_noDups
```

This will classify `rs2` as a duplicate; however, **for the PLINK `list-duplicate-vars` method `rs2` will not be flagged as a duplicate**.

If one want's to obtain the same results using PLINK (a non-trivial task for BGEN file formats since `awk`, `sed` *etc.* **do not work on binary files!**) you can use the [`--rm-dup` command from `PLINK2.0`](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/2.0/filter#rm_dup). The list of all duplicate SNPs removed can be logged (to a file ending in `.rmdup.list`) using the `list` parameter, like so:

```
plink2 --bgen chr22.bgen \
  --sample chr22.sample \
  --rm-dup exclude-all list \
  --export bgen-1.1 \   # Export as bgen version 1.1
  --out chr22_noDups
```

*Note: I'm saving the output as version 1.1 since plink1.9 still has commands not available in plink version 2.0. Therefore the only way to use bgen files with plink1.9 (at this time) is with the older 1.1 version*.